# ld: warning: ignoring file [path], missing required architecture i386 in file

Tags: iphone, xcode4, i386

I get this error message when I try to run the iPhone Simulator. I use Xcode 4

```
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Marius/Documents/AppSchool/Telefonbok/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Marius/Documents/AppSchool/Telefonbok/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ABRecordCopyValue", referenced from:
      -[SecondViewController peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:] in SecondViewController.o
  "_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[SecondViewController peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:] in SecondViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABPeoplePickerNavigationController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SecondViewController.o
  "_kABPersonFirstNameProperty", referenced from:
      -[SecondViewController peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:] in SecondViewController.o
  "_kABPersonLastNameProperty", referenced from:
      -[SecondViewController peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:] in SecondViewController.o
  "_kABPersonPhoneProperty", referenced from:
      -[SecondViewController peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:] in SecondViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the linker is looking for AddressBook.framework and AddressBookUI.framework in `/Users/Marius/Documents/AppSchool/Telefonbok/` and not in the SDK folders. You should check if you added those frameworks correctly to your project.

Answer (score 2):

If you have sure that you properly added the frameworks, see if you have some copies of framework folders (e.g. AddressBookUI) inside the project folder (right click on your project in Xcode and select Show in Finder). If so, just remove them from finder and try build again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the AddressBookUI.framework